# Finding all values in a Dictionary<string, object> where key contains substring

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary declared as follow:

```
Dictionary<string, IData> map;
```

I want to get all the values with the keys containing a specific substring with for example a function like

```
public IEnumerable<IData> GetContains(string pattern) {}
```

And I figured how to obtain a list of keys matching the pattern using

```
var result = mapData.Keys.Where(a => a.Contains(pattern)).ToArray()
```

but I cannot figure out how to reuse the returned keys to get all the corresponding values in one query.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `Where` on your `Dictionary` instead of the `Keys` collection then get the values with `Select`:

```
mapData.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Contains(pattern)).Select(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work

```
var result = mapData.Where(entry => entry.Key.Contains(pattern))
                    .Select(item => item.Value);
```